# Changing main parameter type

Tags: java, eclipse, static, program-entry-point

I'm currently working on a school project in Eclipse (We have just started using this) and we are running into a small hickup: Because we used BlueJ before, we did not have any main method, we added one but ran into a problem.

We have to send an Int value in the parameter instead of a String[] with args, we tried
    public static void main(Int[] args)
This results in the following error:

> Error: Main method not found in class Tester, please define the main
>   method as:    public static void main(String[] args)

I'm wondering what we should do/change to get this to work.

Comment: you should listen to your teacher instead of surfing stackoverflow ;-)

Comment: teacher never mentioned it :(, maybe was a little bit too fast on asking here but at leaast im certain now :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look into `Integer.parseInt("123")`,
see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29

I hope you'll figure out the rest :)

Comment: or equivalent Integer.valueOf(String)

Comment: Yep, but the normal case is the use of the primitive type and not the object, so I would prefer `parseInt`

Comment: Thanks :), all the other people too!

Answer (score 3):

Java will look for `public static void main(String[] args)`.
You will have to pass the integer value as a String and parse it.

Here is a link to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) for `Integer.parseInt(String)`.

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, you cannot change the signature of the `main` method. To obtain an integer from the `String` parameters use:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int first = Integer.parseInt(args[0]); // use whatever index you need
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just like the error says, the main method that will be invoked when you execute the class must have the signature `public static void main(String[] args)`.  You can't just give it different arguments.

If you pass numbers as arguments on the command line, they will be read in as strings by Java.  If you want to convert them to a numeric type, you must do so explicitly in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Try sending your integer in the String array.

```
new String[]{"1"}
```

Then fetch it:

```
Integer yourInteger = Integer.valueOf(args[0])
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass your value as a String then parse it as an Integer.

Look this sample of code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int value = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    System.out.println("My int value: " + value);
}
```

You need to protect the parseInt with try catch for error management, if parameter is not parsable.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass in a string, and then use `Integer.parseInt(string)` to get the integer you need back.

Answer (score 1):

write a main method like below

`public static void main(String[] args){`

`}`.

and use `Integer.parseInt(str)`

Answer (score 1):

You must leave the main method as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    //....
}
```

As you indicate the error. Now, in the main method can change the type of the arguments to integers.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int arg0=Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int arg1=Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    //... etc.
}
```

Regards!

Answer (score 1):

This class will print out the integers you put in on the command line:

```
public class IntegersFromCommandLine
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(args[i]));
        }
    }
}
```

If you give it the command line arguments *1324 21 458 9564 1 0 -789 40*, it will give the following output:

```
1324
21
458
9564
1
0
-789
40
```

Answer (score 0):

The signature of the main method *cannot* be changed. This is a constraint of the operating system.

Just parse the String into an integer via `Integer.parseInt(...)`, then invoke the actual method!